# Using local gems with Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm developing a gem in parallel with my main app. Since I'm making frequent changes, I want to reference that gem from my main project, without having to repeatedly build and release it.

My Gemfile contains the line:

```
gem 'my_gem', :path => '/Users/andy/path/to/my_gem'
```

However, when I run my app's tests using bundle exec, one tests fails and the backtrace shows that the wrong gem location is being used:

```
/Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/my_gem-0.6.0/lib/my_gem/page.rb:23:in `...'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Bundler 1.1.0

Update - excerpt from Gemfile.lock:

```
PATH
  remote: /Users/andy/path/to/my_gem
  specs:
    my_gem (0.6.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      capybara

DEPENDENCIES
  my_gem!
```

It seems wrong that my_gem has a version number beside it, shouldn't it just use the latest code at that path?

Comment: Are you sure you have run `bundle install` after changing the Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I forgot Spork was running, so things weren't being fully reloaded.